# sum to turn divisible by one element of the list each time

Tags: python

Given the list:

```
n = [3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60]
```

I need to turn a random number divisible by 3, after by 6, after by 12, after by 24, after by 36, after by 48 and after by 60. One at each time, not the divisible for the seven numbers simultaneously.

But, to make the number divisible, I need to sum another number to reach the number divisible by 3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48 or 60.

I don't know the random number neither the number to add to this random number in order to turn it divisible by 3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48 or 60.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make a single number divisible by all of these elements, or a list of numbers, each of which is divisible by the corresponding element?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. There are other tutorials online and also some good online/mooc intro computer science classes that use Python for the course.

Comment: Try to do it first for a single number instead of list, and then just add the needed logic to loop a list. hint: `num % d == 0` returns True if `num` is divisible by `d`

Comment: @bruce_skywalker--for your stated problem is my solution correct or incorrect in that for the current problem: the answer is 312, needing and offset of 1, with the common divisor being 3 (see my answer below)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. You say you want the number to be divisible by all numbers in the list, but then you say `In this case: 311 + 1 = 312 `, but 312 is not divisible by 36, 48 or 60.

Comment: @bruce_skywalker, please clarify your question. You have 3 almost different answers here which people take the time to come up with and not even knowing if it is relevant...

Comment: I am looking for a number divisible by 3, after by 6, after by 12, after by 24, after by 36, after by 48 and after by 60, not all simultaneously. I need a small routine to test all numbers divisible giving a random number that I gave the example: 311 + 1 = 312, where the 311 is the random number, 1 is the element I need to add, 312 is the number divisible by 3 and this number is also divisible by 6, 12 and 24. In the case of 36, I need to do 311 + 13 to have 324 (divisible by 36).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer for the clarified question:

```
import math

def f(x, a):
    return math.ceil(a / x) * x - a

n = [3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60]
a = 311
result = [f(x, a) for x in n]
print(result)
```

Old answer:

I think you're looking for the LCM (lowest common multiple) of all numbers in n. We can get the LCM for two numbers [using the GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Using_the_greatest_common_divisor) (greatest common divisor). We can then use reduce to get the LCM for the whole list. Assuming x can be negative, simply subtract a from the LCM to get your answer. The code could look like this:

```
import math
from functools import reduce

def lcm(a, b):  # lowest common multiple
    return a * b // math.gcd(a, b)

n = [3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60]
smallest_divisible_by_all = reduce(lcm, n)

a = 311
x = smallest_divisible_by_all - a
print(x)
```

which outputs

```
409
```

If speed is not important, you could also do a brute force solution like this:

```
ns = [3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60]
a = 311
x = 0

while not all([(a + x) % n == 0 for n in ns]):
    x += 1
```

(assuming that x >= 0)

Comment: No, no, I need to compute the divisors each of the list separately, not simultaneously

Comment: @bruce_skywalker like this?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It worked very well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Using <s>the map function</s> list comprehension:

```
import random

n = [3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60]
a = random.randint(start, stop)

result = [a + x - a % x if a % x else a for x in n]
addition = [x - a for x in result]

print(a)
print(result)
print(addition)
```

`start` and `stop` are the limits for your random number.

Output for a = 311:

```
 311
[312, 312, 312, 312, 324, 336, 360]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 25, 49]
```

---

**Begin of the old answer** to the rather unclear question before the first edit by the author.

The following post answers the question: *Which is the next number after `a`, which is a multiple of all numbers of the list `n`, if it is not `a`?*

First the least common multiple `lcm` of the numbers from the list must be determined. For this purpose, the method `least_common_multiple` is executed for the complete list.  The modulo operation then checks whether `a` is not already a multiple of the numbers. If this is the case, `a` is output. Otherwise, the next multiple of `lcm` is output.

```py
from math import gcd
from functools import reduce

n = [3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60]
a = 311

def least_common_multiple(x, y):
    return abs(x * y) // gcd(x, y)

lcm = reduce(least_common_multiple, n)
result = a if a > 0 else 1  # can be change if necessary, see edit
mod = result % lcm
if mod:
    result += (lcm - mod)

print('Current number: ' + str(a))
print('The next number divisible by any number from the given list: ' + str(result))
print('Necessary addition: ' + str(result - a))
```

Output:

```
Current number: 311
The next number divisible by any number from the given list: 720
Necessary addition: 409
```

**Edit**: Changed the code so that `0` is no longer a valid result for a non-positive `a`.
However, if it is valid, you can change the code at the commented part with: `result = a`.

Answer (score 0):

So I can think of 2 solutions:

First if you want a list which show how much you have to add for the random number to get to a divisible number:

```
def divisible(numbers,random):
    l = []
    for number in numbers:
        if random % number != 0:
            l += [number - (random % number)]
        else:
            l += [0]
    return l

a = 311
n = [3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60]

print(divisible(n,a))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 25, 49]
```

Or if you want to know how far is the smallest number from the random number that everyone shares as divisible. For this take a look how you calculate lcm.

```
from math import gcd

def divisible_all(numbers, random):
    lcm = numbers[0]
    for i in numbers[1:]:
        lcm = lcm*i//gcd(lcm, i)
    tempLcm = lcm
    while lcm < random: # in case the lcm is smaller than the random number add lcm until it is bigger (I assume you only allow positive numbers)
        lcm += tempLcm
    return lcm-random

print(divisible_all(n,a))
```

Output:

409

Comment: The first code is closer to what I need. I just need to add these values [1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 25, 49] to turn the random variable divisible by [3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60].

Comment: @bruce_skywalker if it solved your question then mark it please as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
import math

n = [3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60]

div_n={el: False for el in n}
a=311

a0=math.ceil(a/max(n)) * max(n)

while not all(div_n.values()):
    div_n={el: False for el in n}
#   print(a0)
    for el in n:
        if(a0 % el > 0):
            a0=math.ceil(a0/el) * el
            break
        else:
            div_n[el]=True

print(a0-a)
```

Output:

```py
409
```